# These credentials do not match our records, laravel 5.2

Tags: postgresql, authentication, laravel-5

I am using laravel auth and inserting admin users through DB seeding, I have encrypted passwords also and for "remember_token" I have not touched it. In DB(postgre) user is added with encrypted password and blank remember_token, but when I try to login it shows "These credentials do not match our records".

If I register and do login from register and login pages, it works perfectly fine.

Here is my run() in seeder->

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table ( 'users' )->insert ( array (
            'name' => 'Test',
            'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
            'password'=>bcrypt('test'),
            'created_at'=>new DateTime(),
            'updated_at'=>new DateTime(),
    ) );

    DB::table ( 'users' )->insert ( array (
            'name' => 'Demo',
            'email' => 'demo@gmail.com',
            'password'=>bcrypt('demo'),
            'created_at'=>new DateTime(),
            'updated_at'=>new DateTime(),
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Are you using a postLogin function?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, which postLogin function. But the login form that I am using is same as laravel provides with make:auth

Comment: whats the way you encrypt passwords. Are you using bcrypt? can you show db seeder pls?

Comment: Hey @Dean I have updated my question with seeder.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you define in your User Model your password encryption.

```
/**
 * setPasswordAttribute
 * @param void
 */
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```