# Laravel Problem credentials do not match our records

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

First of all Sorry for my bad english.

I am new to laravel. I have recently run into some problems with authentication/login system which comes built-in in laravel by the command `make:auth`.

The registration process is working correctly and after that it logs me in automatically. but when I log out and try to log back in, I get this error:

> These credentials do not match our records.

I'm not sure whats wrong! but i tried to search error on google stack overflow and etc. The solution i found is this.
[These credentials do not match our records, laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546773/these-credentials-do-not-match-our-records-laravel-5-2)
but it also didn't work.

This is my code.

Http/Auth/LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }


}
```

This is model

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_name', 'email','user_password','user_created_by',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'user_password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }
}
```

This is View

Views/auth/login.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

This is User Table

[User Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhL57.png)

Comment: Just to be sure, is your browser not autocompleting your login form with a wrong password? You can try to see if your hassed password is the same as the one in the database by printing dd(Hash::make($request->password));

Comment: Are you maybe using the user_name to login? By default Laravel will use the email.

Comment: Perrykipkerrie Where do i put this code dd(Hash::make($request->password)); in my files.

Comment: ExCluSiv3 im using email to login.

Answer (score 1):

In the App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'user_name';
}
```

In the App\Http\User model:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->user_password;
}
```

Comment: I Put this code in my LoginController and User Model files. The problem is same that i cant login. But the error  "These credentials do not match our records." is not comming.